# Boolean Operations on Scopes

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I would like to do something similar with my security scopes OAS3 to indicate the permissions such as `(user:write & user:read) | user:admin`

```
/user:
  post:
    responses:
      '200':
        description: Successful operation
    security:
      - app_auth:
        - or:
          - 'user:admin'
          - and:
            - 'user:write'
            - 'user:read'
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be defined as:

```yaml
      security:
        - app_auth:
          - 'user:admin'
        - app_auth:
          - 'user:write'
          - 'user:read'
```